# Dynamically loading images from sd card changes the relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-ndk

**Realtive layout problem**

> Loading images from SD card 
>   Relative layout getting disturbed 
>   How to fix that images get loaded without disturbing the relative layout

Comment: What have you tried? Show us how you load those images. That will be better to anyone who wants to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you need to set the correct size of the images .

here's some documentation of how to deal with bitmaps:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html